# Where is the CPUID string located in the CPU?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm a newbie to CPU architectures and design, I came up with the following question: Where is the CPUID string (like "GenuineIntel") stored?

Is it hard-coded in the microcode ROM? Or is CPUID a low-level instruction, and the string is set up as a configuration of jumpers on the die?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID 

This should have all the answers you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored in a model specific register [MSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register) on intel platforms. This register is accessible programatically. I know that the VC++ compiler has an intrinsic called __readmsr